# Cplex C++, Sum IloNumVarArray and create SOS2

Tags: c++, linear-programming, cplex

I am trying to implement the example 9.8 on page 179 of this book: [link](https://books.google.dk/books?id=YJRh0tOes7UC&pg=PA153&lpg=PA153&dq=non-linear+functions+of+two+or+more+variables+H.+Paul+Williams&source=bl&ots=wqZ6L61yq_&sig=fFYA93B9pqKaI6QQDoAFOclZQ98&hl=da&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8nJOkoOnOAhVKJJoKHRmYBLYQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=non-linear%20functions%20of%20two%20or%20more%20variables%20H.%20Paul%20Williams&f=false)

I am using Cplex with the C++ interface.

I have troubles with initializing the SOS2 correctly. Here is the piece of my code for initializing the SOS2:

```
    IloNumArray Cval(env, S);
    IloNumVarArray C(env,S);
    for (int s = 0; s < S; s++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < K; k++)
        {
            C[s] = IloNumVar(env, 0, 1);                
            C[s] += lamda[s][k];
        }
        Cval[s] = s;
    }
    model.add(IloSOS2(env, C, Cvals));

    IloNumArray Bval(env, K);
    IloNumVarArray B(env,K);                    
    for (int k = 0; k < K; k++)
    {
        for (int s = 0; s < S; s++)
        {
            B[s] = IloNumVar(env, 0, 1);
            B[k] += lamda[s][k];
        }
            Bval[k] = k; 
    }
    model.add(IloSOS2(env, B, Bval));enter code here
```

I get the following error:

```
SOS2Test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
SOS2Test.cpp:74:16: error: no match for ‘operator+=’ (operand types 
are ‘IloNumVar’ and ‘IloNumVar’)
sosvars[s] += lamda[s][k];
            ^
SOS2Test.cpp:87:16: error: no match for ‘operator+=’ (operand types 
are ‘IloNumVar’ and ‘IloNumVar’)
sosvark[k] += lamda[s][k];
            ^
```

which of course if very clear. The operator '+=' is not implemented for that type. However, I cannot think of any other way of doing it and I am pretty sure that is indeed what I want to do.

Can anybody help me out or point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Here is what I am trying to do:

I am trying to approximate a non-linear function of two variables z = f(x,y). I have defined a grid of values (x,y) and associated non-negative weight to each point (i.e. the lamda[s][k]). Then if the values of (x,y) at the grid points are denoted (X[s], Y[s]), then the function can be approximated by the following relations:

```
x = Sum_s Sum_k X[s] * lamda[s][k] 
y = Sum_s Sum_k Y[k] * lamda[s][k] 
z = Sum_s Sum_k Z[s][k] * lamda[s][k]
1 = Sum_s Sum_k Z[s][k] lamda[s][k]
```

where

```
s = rows
k = columns
```

Then in order to use points that are closely related, we need to impose that at most four neighbouring lamda[s][k] can be non-zero. That can be imposed by the following constraints:

```
C[s] = sum_k lamda[s][k] for all s
B[k] = sum_k lamda[s][k] for all k
```

where C {C_1, C_2, .. C_s} and B {B_1, B_2, .. B_k} are taken as SOS2. Which imposes that at most two neighboring rows and two neighboring columns can be non-zero.

The code I have provided is for the last two constraints and what I am trying to do is for instance setting the C[s] (the s'th instance of C) equal to the sum of the lamda over s and k (row and column). Or in other words, for each row of the grid, the sum of the variables in row 1, should go into C[1], the sum of the variables in row 2 should go into C[2] etc. And for each column, the sum of the variables in column 1, should go into B[1] etc.

So in CPLEX term. I want to sum up a set of IloNumVars and set that equal to a position in a IloNumVarArray and then use that IloNumVarArray as a SOS2

I hope this clarifies it a bit.

Comment: I'm still confused by your choice of words.  [SOS constraints](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/discr_optim/sos/02_SOS_defn.html) don't take a sum of variables, they take an ordered set (an array).  I think you want to create a bunch of SOS2 constraints (one for each column and one for each row of `lamda`).  Is that correct?  In your example you are only creating two SOS2 constraints....

Comment: I am pretty sure I only need two SOS2, but it may be me misunderstanding something. I have written down the model in Latex and uploaded it to this [link](https://www.docdroid.net/IN38vY6/example9.pdf.html). I really appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: This is not how to specify a model with SOS sets. What I would do is (1) formulate the model without sos sets (ie use normal variables and constraints). Once this works (export LP file to check) do: (2) add a SOS2 structure, Indeed this approach needs just 2 SOS2 sets. This step would not change anything from step (1): all equations and variables stay the same. We just add two SOS2 sets.

Comment: I posted the solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a solution, thanks to @rkersh, who got me thinking in the right direction. For the interested reader, here is how I solved it:

```
    IloNumVarArray B(env, S);
    IloNumArray Bval(env, S);
    for (int s = 0; s < S; s++)
    {
        B[s] = IloNumVar(env, 0, 1);
        Bval[s] = s;
        IloExpr l(env);
        for (int k = 0; k < K; k++)
        {
            l += lamda[s][k];
        }
        model.add(B[s] == l);
    }
    model.add(IloSOS2(env, B, Bval));

    IloNumVarArray C(env, K);
    IloNumArray Cval(env, K);                   
    for (int k = 0; k < K; k++)
    {
        Cval[k] = k;
        C[k] = IloNumVar(env, 0, 1);
        IloExpr l(env);
        for (int s = 0; s < S; s++)
        {
            l += lamda[s][k];
        }
        model.add(C[k] == l);       
    }
    model.add(IloSOS2(env, C, Cval));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need an SOS2 constraint for every row and column of `lamda`, like so:

```
  for (int s = 0; s < S; s++) {
     model.add(IloSOS2(env, lamda[s]));
  }

  IloNumVarArray B[K];
  for (int k = 0; k < K; k++) {
     B[k] = IloNumVarArray(env, S);
     for (int s = 0; s < S; s++) {
        B[k][s] = lamda[s][k];
     }
     model.add(IloSOS2(env, B[k]));
  }
```

That would produce, for example with a 4x4 matrix, the following SOS2 constraints in LP format:

```
SOS
 s1: S2 ::  x_0_0 : 1  x_0_1 : 2  x_0_2 : 3  x_0_3 : 4
 s2: S2 ::  x_1_0 : 1  x_1_1 : 2  x_1_2 : 3  x_1_3 : 4
 s3: S2 ::  x_2_0 : 1  x_2_1 : 2  x_2_2 : 3  x_2_3 : 4
 s4: S2 ::  x_3_0 : 1  x_3_1 : 2  x_3_2 : 3  x_3_3 : 4
 s5: S2 ::  x_0_0 : 1  x_1_0 : 2  x_2_0 : 3  x_3_0 : 4
 s6: S2 ::  x_0_1 : 1  x_1_1 : 2  x_2_1 : 3  x_3_1 : 4
 s7: S2 ::  x_0_2 : 1  x_1_2 : 2  x_2_2 : 3  x_3_2 : 4
 s8: S2 ::  x_0_3 : 1  x_1_3 : 2  x_2_3 : 3  x_3_3 : 4
```

So, if "x_0_0" is nonzero, then at most, "x_0_1", "x_1_0" and "x_1_1" would also be nonzero.  You can see that the weights are auto-generated.

Comment: That was the solution I went with in the first place. However, by forcing lamda[0][0] >= 0.1 (as a constraint) and maximizing z (the non-linear function). I get a behaviour, where lamda[0][0] is (of course) chosen and then lamda[S][K] is also chosen. Which means I get the convex combination of (0,0) and (S,K) (which is the top right point) and they are not neighbouring. Thinking about it, this makes perfectly sense, as if I have a SOS2 per row and column, then I can chose row 0 and column K and still not violate any constraints. That is why I think only two SOS2 is needed.

Comment: So what I think I need to do is the following: 
Looking at the output you generated, then s1 - s4 needs to be one SOS2 of size 4, where position 0 consists of the sum of x_0_0, x_0_1, x_0_2 and x_0_3, position 1 consists of x_1_0, x_1_1, x_1_2 and x_1_3, etc. The same goes for s5-s8, they also need to be one SOS2. That is how I understand the example I linked. Again, Thank you so much for taking you the time to help me.

Comment: I see what you're saying now.  You can only use sets of variables for the SOS constraints (not sums or constraints), so you'd need to create some new variables to represent/model the sums.  It may be possible to use indicator constraints (`IloIfThen`'s in concert), like `i0 = 1 -> x_0_0 + x_0_1 + x_0_2 + x_0_3 = 1`,  `i0 = 0 -> x_0_0 + x_0_1 + x_0_2 + x_0_3 = 0`  for each "sum".  Then using the indicator variables in the corresponding SOS2 constraint would look like: `S2 :: i0:1 i1:2 i2:3 i3:4`.  Does that sound right?

Comment: Yes that may be it. I will have a look tomorrow as it is getting really late here and let you know. Really, you have been a great help so far! Thanks

Comment: @rkersh I don't see the need for indicators in this case (actually I believe they would destroy the interpolation scheme). The description in Williams is actually quite good.